# Print SQL query of ORM query builder in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

How to print ORM query

```
$query = $articles->find('all')->contain(['Comments']);
```

For example print =>

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id IN (comments);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrapping your ORM query result with the debug function will show the SQL and bound params:

```
debug($query);
```

You can also similarly look at the query results with the debug function.See [CakePHP 3: retrieving data and result sets — Debugging Queries and ResultSets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#debugging-queries-and-resultsets)

Comment: Do you know how to print only sql part of it?

Comment: Did you try string casting it? `(string)$query`.

Answer (score 11):

what about `$query->sql()`?

```
$qb = $this->Person->find()->select(["id", "text" => "concat(Name,' ',Family)"])
            ->where(['id >' => 0])
            ->where($query ? ["OR" => $filters] : null)
            ->limit(10);
dd($qb->sql());
```

and result:

```
.../src/Controller/ClientController.php (line 86)
'SELECT Person.id AS `Person__id`, concat(Name,' ',Family) AS `text` FROM person Person WHERE (id > :c0 AND (Family like '%sam%' OR Name like '%sam%' OR Family like '%sam%' OR Name like '%sam%')) LIMIT 10'
```

Comment: The official DebugKit plugin has the [helper functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html#helper-functions) that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this:

```
public function __debugInfo()
    {
        return [
            'query' => $this->_query,
            'items' => $this->toArray(),
        ];
    }

// Print the query
debug($query->__debugInfo()['sql']);

// Prints this
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id IN (comments);
```